# Two colors images compression algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, image

What is the best (minimize size) compression algorthm for images with only two colors? And the fastest?

Comment: Do you mean black and white or RGB?

Comment: It depends strongly on what kind of image. Pure random noise images are challenging to compress (:)). A function plot can be compressed to it's expression and bounds, etc.

Comment: I mean an image with only two color (eg black and white) as a matrix of 0/1 elements.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the image looks like. If it's mostly large blotches of color then you may do well with [Run Length Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). If it's constantly changing colors, you might make a matrix of bits corresponding to the pixels and then compress that with [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZW).

Answer (score 1):

The method used by [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Compression) would be pretty good, it combines prediction and compression.

Answer (score 0):

[DjVu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DjVu) is know to compress certain 2-color bitmaps, like text, pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Jbig2 would be one of the best compressions and it is supported by Adobereader